# Syntax for using a generic type as struct field

Tags: go, syntax

I am trying to define a table type in Golang using structs. This is what I have at the moment.

```
type Column[T any] struct {
    Name   string
    Values map[int]T
}
```

I would like to use this column type to define a table like so,

```
type Table struct {
//Following line returns an error
    Columns map[string]Column
```

Go's compiler is throwing an error that I need to instantiate the generic type Column.

Can anyone help me with the syntax for creating it?

Comment: Would you expect `Table`'s `Columns` field to contain several instances of `Column` with different types (ie `Column[string]` and `Column[uint64]` and the like?). Because `Table[T any]` + `Columns map[string]Column[T]` will work, but your table can only contain columns of a specific type.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Yes, I will need to have columns of different types.

Comment: You can't. By mixing and matching types at the table level, you essentially need type erasure, whereas golang generics don´t work that way. A `Column[string]` is not the same as a `Column[int]`. Generic code to handle iterating over your columns, each time accessing `col.Values[k]` is not possible, because depending on the type of the column, the value returned by that expression is going to be a different type. You'll need to manually handle the different value types at some point anyway. You could abstract some of it behind an interface, but it still leaves you with the type issue.

Answer (score 3):

You need to propagate the type from top level structure:

```
type Table[T any] struct {
    Columns map[string]Column[T]
}
```

See [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/jSSS2mowhOj)

Comment: I need to have columns of different (generic) types. It looks like this table can only contain columns of one type which is too limiting.

If it is not possible with structs, let me know of any other construct in golang I can use instead.

Comment: You don't have a set of types you want to use ? Or you really want `any` ? Ideally, you may declare multiple type

Comment: For now, I don't know what types I would need in the future, so I just set it to any. At the moment I only need to support ints, strings, and maps in columns but I don't see how would it simplify the problem.

Answer (score 2):

So what you're trying to do do is essentially have a number of columns, with values in different types, and collect them all in a `Table` type. Using plain old generics, you can do something like Ado Ren suggested:

```
type Column[T any] struct {
    Name   string
    Values map[int]T
}

type Table[T any] struct {
    Columns map[string]Column[T]
}
```

However, as I suspected, you want your `Table` to be able to contain multiple columns, of different types, so something like this would not work:

```
sCol := Column[string]{
    Name: "strings",
}
uiCol := Column[uint64]{
    Name: "Uints",
}
tbl := Table[any]{
    Columns: map[string]any{
        sCol.Name:  sCol,
        uiCol.Name: uiCol,
    },
}
```

The reason, if you look at what this implies, is that the type for `tbl` doesn't make sense, compared to the values you're assigning. The `any` (or `interface{}` type means that what `tbl` is initialised to - and what it expects - is this (I replaced the `Column` type with an anonymous struct so the type mismatch is more obvious):

```
Table[any]{
    Columns: map[string]struct{
        Name   string
        Values map[int]any // or interface{}
    }{
        "Strings": {
            Name:   "Strings",
            Values: map[int]string{}, // does not match map[int]any
        },
        "Uints": {
            Name:   "Uints",
            Values: map[int]uint64{}, // again, not a map[int]any
        },
    }
}
```

This is essentially what is going on. Again, and as I mentioned in a comment earlier, there's a reason for this. The whole point of generics is that they allow you to create types and write meaningful functions that can handle all types governed by the constraint. With a generic `Table` type, should it accept differently typed `Column` values, that no longer applies:

```
func (t Table[T any]) ProcessVals(callback func(v T) T) {
    for _, col := range t.Columns {
        for k, v := range col.Values {
            col.Values[k] = callback(v)
        }
    }
}
```

With a type like `Table[uint64]`, you could do stuff like:

```
tbl.ProcessVals(func(v uint64) uint64 {
    if v%2 == 1 {
        return v*3 + 1
    }
    return v/2
})
```

But if some of the columns in table are strings, then naturally, this callback makes no sense. You'd need to do stuff like:

```
tbl.ProcessVals(func (v interface{}) interface{} {
    switch tv := t.(type) {
    case uint64:
    case int64:
    case int:
    case uint:
    default:
        return v
    }
})
```

Use type switches/type assertions to make sense of each value, and then process it accordingly. That's not really generic... it's basically what we did prior to the introduction of go generics, so why bother? At best it makes no difference, at worst you'll end up with a lot of tedious code all over the place, as callbacks are going to be written by the caller, and their code will end up a right mess.

---

### So what to do?

Honestly, this question has a bit of the X-Y problem feel about it. I don't know what you're trying to do exactly, so odds are you're just going about it in the sub-optimal way. I've been vocal in the past about not being the biggest fan of generics. I use them, but sparingly. More often than not, I've found (in C++ templates especially), people resort to generics not because it makes sense, but because they can. Be that as it may, in this particular case, you can incorporate columns of multiple types in your `Table` type using one of golangs more underappreciated features: duck-type interfaces:

```
type Column[T any] struct {
    Name   string
    Values map[int]T
}

type Col interface {
    Get() Column[any]
}

type Table struct {
    Columns map[string]Col
}

func (c Column[T]) Get() Column[any] {
    r := Column[any]{
        Name:   c.Name,
        Values: make(map[int]any, len(c.Values)),
    }
    for k, v := range c.Values {
        r.Values[k] = v
    }
    return r
}
```

Now `Table` doesn't expect a `Column` of any particular type, but rather any value that implements the `Col` interface (an interface with a single method returning a value of `Column[any]`). This effectively erases the underlying types as far as the Table is concerned, but at least you're able to cram in whatever `Column` you like.

### [Demo](https://go.dev/play/p/xqpm2atqkQy)

#### Constraints

If relying on a simple interface like this isn't to your taste (which, in some cases, is not desirable), you could opt for a more controlled approach and use a type constraint, in conjunction with the above `Get` method:

```
type OrderedCols interface {
    Column[uint64] | Column[int64] | Column[string] // and so on
}

type AllCols interface {
    // the OrderCols constraint, or any type
    Column[any] | OrderedCols
}
```

With these constraints in place, we can make our `Table` type a bit safer to use in the sense that we can ensure the `Table` is guaranteed to only contain actual `Column[T]` values, not something else that just happens to match the interface. Mind you, we still have some types to erase:

```
type Table[T AllCols] struct {
    Columns map[string]T
}

tbl := Table[Column[any]]{
    Columns: map[string]Column[any]]{
        c1.Name: c1.Get(), // turn in to Column[any]
        c2.Name: c2.Get(),
    },
}
```

### [Demo here](https://go.dev/play/p/IU9JQrfnEaV)

Comment: Thank you for writing such a detailed response. However, generics have some use cases I will definitely need. I am still leaning go if those are not supported in Go, I will choose a language that does. It is more important than the support for concurrency go provides. 

I  don't know Golang a lot but it looks like the type erasure you are suggesting would make type assisted intellisense stop working. Correct me if I am wrong about it.

Comment: @Hashir I have no clue as to intellisense. I use lsp in vim, and if `Table` is populated with `Column[any]` there's no reason why autocomplete would stop working. I never said generics have no use cases BTW, I use them myself. I just think that an interface may be a better fit at the Table level, the column type is something akin to a little package I wrote in response to a question a few months ago [called smap](https://github.com/EVODelavega/smap) - generic, _"thread-safe"_ maps